# Postgresql: selecting tables where table names are stored as content in another table

Tags: postgresql, select

I have a table which contains table names (column name is tablename - 1000 rows).  I want to loop through this table constructing a select statement to access the data inside each table. I can loop through the table with no problems, but can't find a way to insert the content (actual name of the table) into the select statement.

```
...
hold_tablename = a_rec.tablename;
query1 := 'SELECT * FROM hold_tablename'; 
--  Postgres thinks 'hold_tablename' is the name of the table rather than
-- looking into the content of that field which should be aaa_customer_tbl.

<<innerloop>> 
FOR b_rec IN EXECUTE query1
loop
   select * from b_rec;
end loop innerloop;
```

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM ' || hold_tablename `  variables do not interpolate inside quotes.

Comment: @clamp Until `hold_tablename` is something like `'white space'` or `'CaseSensitive'`.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: it worked very well.  Thank you, mu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to interpolate an identifier into a string is to use [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) with a `%I` specifier:

```
query1 := format('SELECT * FROM %I', hold_tablename);
```

That will take care of properly quoting `hold_tablename` in case it is case sensitive or contains spaces or other problematic characters.

Alternatively you could use `quote_ident` and string concatenation:

```
query1 := 'SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident(hold_tablename);
```

but `format` is less noisy.

Comment: The URL supplied above goes on to say: *"The %I and %L format specifiers are particularly useful for safely constructing dynamic SQL statements."*   [See Example 43.1.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE)